# What is the complexity analysis for AES encryption algorithm with 3 different key size?

Tags: encryption, aes

I tried to find the complexity for AES (Advanced Encryption Algorithm) but sometime I got constant time and sometime polynomial. Can anyone explain the exact time and space complexity for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encryption/ Decryption time of AES, Blowfish, and PBE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678293/encryption-decryption-time-of-aes-blowfish-and-pbe)

Comment: This largely depends on the implementation and the capabilities of your CPU. For example, on my CPU AES-256 from OpenSSL is much faster in some conditions compared to AES-128.